# find and read a directory of files in node.js

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to find and read a directory of files in Node js.   I want to get hold of a series of html files that exist inside of a templates directory.

I am using  **fs**

```
    var Templates = fs.readdir('../Templates/', function (err, files) {

    if (err) {
        console.log('err', err);
    }
    else {
        files.filter(function (file) { return file.substr(-5) === '.html' });
    }


});
console.log('Templates',Templates);
```

It makes sense to use readdir that comes with fs.

When I run node to look I am getting an error back in my terminal

```
err { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'c:\HA\VSTS\Applications\Templates']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: 'c:\\HA\\VSTS\\Applications\\Templates' }
```

Path is just short in the error message.  I tried

```
  ../../Templates and it returned an incorrect path.
```

I need to be getting

```
  path: 'c:\\HA\\VSTS\\Applications\\ha.web.main\\Templates' }
```

I am not sure how to fix the error or get to the html files.

Comment: try adding a trailing slash after Templates.

Comment: Did not fix my error but that is definitely a fix I need thanks.

Comment: does the user running your program have read access to that directory?  If not they won't be able to see it.

Comment: try flipping the slashes or use a system agnostic file separator character.  '..\Templates\'.  For example on node.js you can use path.sep https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_sep

Comment: your current file under this folder `c:\\HA\\VSTS\\Applications\\`?

Comment: Ok got it   I needed to add ha.web.main  which is the directory that I am in to the solution.  Not sure if to put this as an answer or delete the q.  Since it was a simple fix.

Comment: Why do you use "__dirname" and add your file => direct file location.